# Node.js error on import module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have created this 2 files from TS language specification manual (page 111)

File geometry.ts:

```
export interface Point { x: number; y: number };
export function point(x: number, y: number): Point { return { x: x, y: y }; }
```

File game.ts:

```
import g = require("geometry"); var p = g.point(10, 20);
```

I try the following in command line:

```
tsc geometry.ts -d -m "commonjs"
tsc game.ts -m "commonjs"
node game.ts
```

I get the following error.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'geometry'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Temp\Temp\game.js:1:71)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: You should run `node game.js` instead of `node game.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the geometry module is in your working directory, you need to do require('./geometry') instead of require('geometry')